# How do we get actual researchers involved?

Tags: discussion, promotion

One of my hopes is that this really becomes a community of experts and researchers. I'd like to have people who are actively growing our knowledge included in the conversation, rather than just another place where basic or complex questions are asked and answered by multiple practitioners based on experience alone (albeit a better place because of the reputation system).

How could we make this forum interesting to researchers?

Answer (score 1):

It would be cool to have more researchers. Perhaps you could take the initiative in bringing more of them folk over here, as you seem to be one yourself? I know UIE is big on research; would Jared and crew be up to getting involved? What about communities around Jakob Nielsen or Steve Krug? (Slap me if I don't know what I'm talking about, I'm just naming names I know)